# DAX measure to calculate difference between selected slicer value of column YEAR and the rest of the values in column YEAR

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard

I have a dahsboard where I select year and charts are filtered based on the year selection. I have a line chart which is not linked to the slicer (interactions turned off) but I would like to display data related to 6 years prior to the date selected. Hence I thoght of creating a measure value that subtracts the selected year with the remaining years and apply that as a filter to my chart so I display values only where difference is 1,2,3,4,5 or 6.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a sample of the code you've tried to get running. Check out this page as well, it's not ment for it to be more difficult for you to post but rather make it easier for us to give you the correct answer. [HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure to calculate the difference and use [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) to get the year selected in the slicer. If we say, that you have a table named `Table (Data)` with column `Year` containing your data, and table named `Table (Years)` with column `Year`, which is your calendar table containing the list of years shown in the slicer, then the measure can be calculated like this:

```
Measure_Diff = SELECTEDVALUE('Table (Years)'[Year]) - MAX('Table (Data)'[Year])
```

Then you will get the number of years difference between the year in your data table and the one selected by the user:

[image]

Comment: I've tried that I just get -2020 as the answer for all values in Measure_Diff